# Checkbox with Custom listview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I am using cursoradapter to get the values from database and to display it in listview.I am able to show the database contents in listview also onclick of perticular item I am getting value of clicked Item.Now I want checkbox also so that oncheck I should get the values of checked Items ( In this case both checkbox click and listitemclick both should work) is it possible? how to do it?

```
private void displayListView() {
        final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_BIRTHDAY,

        };
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.name,
                R.id.birthdate,
        };
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.rownew,
                cursor,
                columns,    
                to);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customdialog, null);
        ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listChildren);
        final EditText etChild = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etChild);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)) .getText().toString();
                BirtDate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.birthdate)) .getText().toString();
                Log.d("*************", name);

                Info=name+ " " +BirtDate;
                Log.d("nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",Info);
                etChild.setText(new StringBuilder().append(Info));
                topaste=etChild.getText().toString();
                    etChild.setText(new StringBuilder().append(Info1));
                //                  topaste1=etChild.getText().toString();
                //              }


            }
        })
```

My rownew.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/birthdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

My Customdialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etChild"
         android:hint=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listChildren"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </ListView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am inflating it in above class View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customdialog, null);
  ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listChildren);

Comment: Post your custom class code or Post your full java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` to add a click listener for your checkbox. Here is a snippet of the code I use:

```java
public class MultiSelectCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

  public MultiSelectCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int fposition = position;
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox);
    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("CHECKER", "Something happened: " + fposition + " was clicked " + isChecked);
            // TODO: store id of checked items in your model
            }

    });

    return view;
    }
}
```

In your list row layout you need to set `android:focusable="false"` in order to allow clicks on list items *and* clicks on the checkbox of each list item.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/list_checkbox"
        android:focusable="false" 
        ... >
</CheckBox>
```

Finally you need a model or data structure to store all checked items of your list, e.g. an array or list that stores identifiers for all checked items.

Comment: In my main class from where should I write MultiSelectCursorAdapter

Comment: Add this as new class and simply replace `SimpleCursorAdapter` with `MultiSelectCursorAdapter`. You should use the constructor with the `flags` parameter as recommended in the javadoc.

Comment: I am new to this concepts can you give some detail solution

Comment: Please tell me which part you don't understand. It's hard to tell from your comment.